# TypeScript date timezone conflict between client and backend

Tags: typescript, datetime

In our angular app, we pick a `Date` object with a primeNG calendar, for example 20.09.2018.

A `console.log()` of that date returns the correct `Thu Sep 20 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200` (GMT+2 is my local timezone).

This data is posted to our node.js backend, which stores the date to an oracle database. The backend however receives the value `19.09.2018 22:00`, so it seems as if it is set to GMT timezone.

How can I make sure that on the backend side, the timezone is ignored and that `20.09.2018 00:00` is being stored?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the timezone information on your time using [toDateString]

```
date.toDateString()
```

And you can convert your data to your timezone whenever you receive it from the server

```
new Date("string of date send by server")
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem yesterday after calling `toISOString()`. The problem is, as you noticed, that the parser takes timezone offset into account. I tried solving the problem with `.toDateString()` but was still getting the same problem. At the end I went for brute force and did this:

```
const dateNum = Date.parse(selectedDate.toString().substring(0, 28));
const date = new Date(dateNum);
```

The first 28 characters are everything up to but excluding the plus sign. The string that it returns dumps timezone offset so it is treated as if it was created in a GMT time zone. This might not be the most efficient way of solving the problem, but it does the job.